# Schur Numbers but slightly different

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

For $r ≥ 1$ I need to somehow show that there exists a smallest natural number $S'(r)$, such
that every $r$ − coloring of the integers ${1, 2, . . . , N }$, with $N$ ≥ $S'(r)$,
will necessarily contain three integers $x$, $y$, $z$, of the same color, such that
$z = xy$.

I do know Schur's theorem and I can see the obvious similarity, but I can't seem to connect it with this one.

Any inputs would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to say something to exclude the trivial monochromatic solution $x=y=z=1$, which is always there.

In fact, we can prove this statement with the extra property that $x,y,z$ are powers of $2$ greater than $1$. This follows by applying Schur's Theorem to the powers of 2.

By Schur's Theorem, let $S(r)$ be such that every $r$-coloring of $\{1,2,\ldots,S(r)\}$ contains monochromatic $x$, $y$, and $x+y$. Now let $N=2^{S(r)}$. Consider an $r$-coloring of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$. Now restrict this coloring to the subset $\{2^k:1\leq k\leq S(r)\}$, and transfer it to a coloring of $\{1,2,\ldots,S(r)\}$ using $2^k\mapsto k$. I leave the rest to you.

In conclusion, we get $S'(r)\leq 2^{S(r)}$ where $S(r)$ is the standard additive Schur number for $r$-colorings.

Comment: It is quite helpful, could you please explain the part of "restrict this coloring to the subset", I don't quite get it. An example would be nice. Thank you

Comment: You have a coloring of $X=\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$ with $r$ colors. Let $Y=\{2,4,8,16,\ldots,2^{S(r)}\}$. Then $Y$ is a subset of $X$ so you *automatically* get an $r$-coloring of $Y$ by just restricting your attention only to elements in $Y$ (forget about everything else in $X$).

Comment: For example suppose $S=4$ and $N=2^S=16$. Color $X=\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ with three colors (red, green, blue) according to their remainder mod 3 (0, 1, or 2). So $X$ is colored GBRGBRGBRGBRGBRG.  In this case the subset $Y$ is $\{2,4,8,16\}$ which is colored: BGBG.